# Calculations being being rounded SQL Server 2012

Tags: calculated-columns, decimalformat, rounding-error

I am trying to calculate some performance metrics as `[RATE]` in SQL but no matter what I do I am only getting integer values in return.

In my dataset I have a Numerator and a Denominator both stored as integers that are broken down into groups and subsets. The rate is calculated slightly differently depending on the group and subset. For group 1 the calculation is simply N/D. For group 2 the calculation is (N*1000)/D with the exception of 1 subset which is calculated (N*10000)/D.

I wrote the query as:

```
SELECT [Group]
      ,[SubSet]
      ,[Numerator] N
      ,[Denominator] D
      ,CASE WHEN D=0 Then NULL
        WHEN [Group]='G1' THEN [N]/[D]
        WHEN [SubSet]='S2' THEN ([N]*10000)/[D]
        WHEN [SubSet] NOT LIKE 'S2%' AND [G] NOT LIKE 'G1%' THEN ([N]*1000)/[D] as [RATE]
```

No matter what I do the outcome variables are integers. I tried formatting `RATE` as `varchar`, `decimal`, and `float` with no success. I tried changing N and D's format to `varchar`, `decimal`, and `float` as well. I tried changing the equations from `(N*1000)/D` to `(N/D)*1000` but still no effect.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because SQL is doing integer division, which will only return whole numbers. To get a decimal return value you must have at least one value as a decimal.

Try this:

```
(CAST([N] as decimal(12,6))/[D]) * 1000
```

Adjust `decimal(12,6)` based on the precision you are expecting. `12,6` will return a decimal with 6 digits after the decimal point. If you wanted only 2 decimal places use `16,2`.

If you then want to round the calculated value you will need to make use of the `ROUND` function in SQL.

Round to the second decimal place:

```
ROUND((CAST([N] as decimal(12,6))/[D]) * 1000, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CAST:

```
CAST ((N*1000) AS FLOAT) / D
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT (n * 1000.0)` will do it.